# Finding both the longest and shortest path in a convex polygon

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, computational-geometry

Let $S$ be a convex polygon on $n$ points. Given two points $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is left of $S$, and $B$ is right of $S$, what's an algorithm to find the shortest path from $A$ to $B$, that avoids the interior of $S$? What about the longest path?

Comment: Are A and B on the edges of S, or are they vertices of S? Are you asking how to choose the shorter of the two paths around the border of a polygon?

Comment: A and B are not points of S. A is left of S & B is right of S.

Comment: Is the longest path even well defined here? If I give you a path, can't you always find a longer one?

Comment: To make your question more clear you should use words *outside* and *around* instead of *in*.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest path will be made out of straight lines connecting A, B and the vertices of S.

The most simple solution is to check a bunch of paths, starting with path AB; then AXB and AYB where X and Y are the topmost and bottommost points of S; then extending to the left or right neighbors of X and Y, if some intersections happen.

A smarter solution would be to find the points P, minimizing and maximizing the angle between $\vec {AP}$ and $\vec {AB}$. Those will be the points where your path enters and leaves S.

The longest path is, obviously, infinite.

Comment: would not the shortest path be the shortest edge ? can there be any two points not going through the interior and also smaller than smallest edge ?

Comment: @AshishNegi [I think this needs a drawing](http://i.imgur.com/zhbICDQ.gif). Blue is S, red is the shortest path. What edge are you talking about?

Comment: got it thank you. confused with path and straight lines.